# javascript - parse key value json inside html comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have an html page with a single-line javascript comment as follows:

```
// {"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}, {"key3":"value3"} 
<b> Sample Text </b>
```

I want to retrieve all the key value pairs in the comment and place them in javascript maps. How would I parse it using js/jquery? I am terrible at regexes so any help would be appreciated. If it helps, The comment will always be only the first line in the html.

**EDIT:**

If it makes the job easier, I could also work with -

```
/* {"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}, {"key3":"value3"} */ 
<b> Sample Text </b>
```

Comment: Why have a javascript comment in your markup? Can this data not be retrieved after the page loads, or at least be put in a script tag?

Comment: no. its html data retrieved from a server

Comment: If you have access to the html that's being generated, I'd say change it to at least write to a script tag, and definitely not to the very top of the markup. This seems like a very odd practice to me.

Comment: its just a temporary hack. If I put it within a script tag, how would I then process it?

Comment: Well if you put the script tag inside the head, you could just write var x = [{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}, {"key3":"value3"}], then you just access your key value pairs with x[0], x[1], x[2]. Instead of an array, though, you'd probably want something more like { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }

Comment: Its going to all be retrieved as a string. so it will be something like var stringContent = "var x = [{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}, {"key3":"value3"}]". How would I execute it as javascript?

Comment: I think I can use eval(). Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: On the client side, when the page loads, the string you write will get interpeted as javascript and you'll be able to manipulate your data through the "x" object. Don't worry about stringContent. You shouldn't have to use eval.

Comment: As I said, I retrieve this html via an http request to my server. So there's no telling when I will retrieve it. Also, if you'd make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: ok saw that you just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the javascript to the top of the HTML, write it inside a script element like so:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" } ;
</script>
</head>
<!-- REST OF HTML -->
```

You should have access to x with your data like any other javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery function parseJSON

like:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

you could then write that value to your html

Answer (score 0):

`{"(\w+?)":"(\w+?)"}`

That will grab you the key and value. Key is in group 1, value in group 2.

For Javascript, raynjamin has pointed out you'll need the `/g` modifier to match *all* instances of the key-value pairs.

[Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?31atq).

Comment: Don't forget the /g to match all the instances. And how do we get the string to begin with?